# Reactjs - better solution for setState inside fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This problem was basically solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067364/set-reactjs-state-asynchronously) but It's a little bit outdated.

I was trying to set state after fetch is done. Unfortunately the basic solution putting fetch in `ComponentDidMount()` is not working as I wanted (it shows that state is undefined) so I've found around solution like this: declaring global variable, assing fetched data to this global variable and then in `then()` do `this.setState()`. It's working but I have a feeling this is not a completely correct solution.

**Is there a better/cleaner way to do setState inside fetch?**

Here's fragment of my code:

```js
var fetchedData = null;

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        data: "",
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("some-url", {
            credentials: "include",
        }).then((res) => {
            res.json()
                .then((data) => {
                    fetchedData = data;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    if (fetchedData.someData) {
                        this.setState({ data: fetchedData.someData });
                    }
                });
        });
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use a global variable here. Why not just use `setState` in your `json()` callback?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this callback. Could you show how it would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        data: "",
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let res = await fetch("some-url", {credentials: "include"});
        let data = await res.json();
        if (data.someData) {
            this.setState({ data: data.someData });
         } 
        });
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("some-url", {
            credentials: "include",
        }).then((res) => res.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({data}));
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It was my basic solution but in some cases it showed that state was `undefined`.